# Print unique specific text form a line if it meet the search criteria

Tags: awk

I Have the following input.txt file

```
service commands 1 description 'Desc 1 patternid com3'
service commands 2 description 'Desc 1 patternid com3 from err1'
service commands 3 description 'Desc 2 patternid com3 from err2'
service commands 4 description 'Desc 2 patternid com3 from err3'

service commands 1000 description 'to value1 patternid from 1000'
service commands 1001 description 'to value1 patternid from 1001'

service commands 2000 description 'Desc 3 patternid com'
service commands 2001 description 'Desc 3 patternid com2 from err1'
service commands 2002 description 'Desc 4 patternid com2'
service commands 2003 description 'Desc 4 patternid com2 from err1'

service commands 4000 description 'output patternid to com1'
service commands 5000 description 'input to com1'
service commands 6000 description 'input to com2'
```

I want with awk to take the unique descriptions from lines where the service commands number meet the criteria between 1-1000 and 2000-4000
But I want only the description text that is before the word "patternid"

I have found this for the search

```
awk -F'_' '($1>1999 && $1<4000){print}' input.txt
```

But I can't make to search in 3nd filed and for multiple values

I can print the description with

```
awk -F"service commands |description |'" '/service commands/ && /description /{for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) printf"%s", $i ; print""}' input.txt
```

But this not what i want

My desire output is

```
Desc 1
Desc 2
Desc 3
Desc 4
```

How can I do it with one awk command or a combination of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '
    ( ((1 < $3) && ($3 < 1000)) || ((2000 < $3) && ($3 < 4000)) ) &&
    sub(/[^\047]+\047/,"") && sub("patternid.*","") && !seen[$0]++
' file
Desc 1
Desc 2
Desc 3
Desc 4
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Can you add a search in line pattern for "service commands" and for "description" because my file has and other line with other commands and I need to search only in lines that contains those words. And also can I search for a single criterion at a time e.g. 1-1000

Comment: @swa056 the script I posted produces the output you asked for from the input you provided. If the posted sample input and expected output in your question isn't adequate to test your requirements then please update them. With respect to "And also..." - yes, one criteria is easier to search for than multiple. Given all of that though, instead of changing this question you should just ask a new followup question since [Chameleon Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged.

Comment: Sorry I did not give all my claims from the beginning. Your answer works perfect and I managed to customize it with only one search criteria. But because there is a possibility of a wrong search for this and I asked to be able to add a search patterns to eliminate any case of error but this does not mean that your answer does not work. Thank you again for your solution and I will ask a new question for patterns search.

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples only, could you please try following.

```
awk '
/[0-9]+ description.*Desc[[:space:]]+[0-9]+[[:space:]]+patternid/ && (($3>=1 && $3<=1000) || ($3>=2000 && $3<=4000)) && !arr[$5,$6]++{
  sub(/^\047/,"",$5)
  print $5 OFS $6
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Checking if regex pattern `[0-9]+ description.*Desc[[:space:]]+[0-9]+[[:space:]]+patternid` is found in current line(as per OP's requirement), then checking conditions either 3rd field value comes in range of 1 to 1000 OR 3rd field range is coming from 2000 to 4000 AND then checking a condition if 5th and 6th fields combine are NOT present in array then print that value(to get unique values in output).

---

---

***2nd solution:***

```
awk '
match($0,/^service commands [0-9]+[[:space:]]+description.*Desc [0-9]+ patternid/) && (($3>=1 && $3<=1000) || ($3>=2000 && $3<=4000)){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/.*Desc/,"Desc",val)
  sub(/ patternid/,"",val)
  if(!arr[val]++){ print val }
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above(following is only for explanation purposes, for running code use above).

```
# Starting awk program from here.
awk '

    # Using match function to match regex to make sure line has exact format
    # needed by OP. Then checking conditions either 3rd field value comes in
    # range of 1 to 1000 OR 3rd field range is coming from 2000 to 4000.
    match($0, /^service commands [0-9]+[[:space:]]+description.*Desc [0-9]+ patternid/) &&
            (($3 >= 1 && $3 <= 1000) || ($3 >= 2000 && $3 <= 4000)) {

        # Creating val which has sub string of matched regex.
        val = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)

        # Globally substituting everything till Desc with Desc in val here.
        gsub(/.*Desc/, "Desc", val)

        # Substituting space patternid with NULL in val here.
        sub(/ patternid/, "", val)

        # Checking condition if entry is not already present in arr then print val here.
        if ( !seen[val]++ ) {
            print val
        }
    }

# Mentioning Input_file name here.
' Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my problem is that values that I want to get is not always start with the word "Desc" and a number but it can be anything.